# Ubercart 2.x drupal 6 combo attributes price

Tags: ubercart

Is it possible to set a different price for each combination of attributes in Drupal? For example when A and C, the price is $10; when I select B and C, the price is $12; when I select B and D, the price is $13.
I see http://drupal.org/project/uc_custom_price; it works, but I have too much combination for each product. There is a module, http://www.ubercart.org/project/attr_combo_price, but it is for Drupal 5.

Are there any other solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Would [Ubercart Attribute Tokens](http://drupal.org/project/uc_attribute_tokens) help you out here?